# jquery filtering out results when select boxes haven't been, umm, selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, filter

I'm after a little help with a complicated (for me!) jquery statement...

Basically I have a questionnaire, with 30 questions.
Each question (in a table row) is made up of a group of 5 radio buttons.
However, for some questions, as well as the radio group, there is also a select box - for this question to be 'complete' the select box needs to have a value selected (the first option having an empty value) as well as a radio selected.

OK - so I want to show how many questions have been completed - or how many are left to do...

So I need to count up each row considered 'complete' - in pseudo, something like

```
count the number of rows with
radio buttons and one of those radios selected
but remove any row which also has a select box, if that select box hasnt had an option chosen
```

Hope that makes sense...

I can get all the questions where there are unselected radios -

```
var unanswered = $('#myTable tr:has(:radio):not(:has(:radio:checked))').length;
```

or kill the not to count those rows with selected radios, but the select boxes are killing me. Just can't seem to grab hold of those rows with an unselected select box, not to mention combining it with the radio part!

Any help very very appreciated!

Thanks, Calvin

Comment: Could you set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to get the best answers?

Comment: Never tried one...but here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/DBAf7/8/

Comment: Nice one for the jsFiddle recommendation! Working version - least I hope so - is http://jsfiddle.net/qUUJk/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var unanswered2 = $('#myTable tr:has(option):not(:has(option[value!=""]:selected))').length;
```

^Get all `tr` with `option`'s but not those which have empty `value` and are selected. (Not tested on animals).

edit: I have add `!`.

Comment: Edited. I made mistake 1st time.

Comment: Brilliant lord_t! That sorts out the select boxes - thanks!
Think I can manage (think!) to combine the 2 now...I'll give it a go at least :-)

Comment: Yeah I think I jumped the gun a little (not with your code, works a charm) - just combining isn't as straight forward as I hoped! I'll take a break and look later, going blind looking at it!

Comment: Righto - cracked it (he says) - 
var answered= $('#myTable tr:has(:radio):has(:radio:checked)').not(':has(option):not(:has(option[value!=""]:selected))').length;

Many thanks again...